# Image segmentation for extracting letters

Tags: python, opencv, contour, image-segmentation

I am trying to extract the individual letters from the below image [image]

Below is the code which I implemented for the segmentation

```
img = cv.imread('image10.jpg')

img_gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh2 = cv.threshold(img_gray, 150, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
kernel = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (1,1))
mask = cv.morphologyEx(thresh2, cv.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)
bboxes = []
bboxes_img = img.copy()
contours = cv.findContours(mask, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = imutils.grab_contours(contours)
contours = sort_contours(contours, method= "left-to-right")[0]
for cntr in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv.boundingRect(cntr)
    cv.rectangle(bboxes_img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0,0,255), 1)
    bboxes.append((x,y,w,h))

cv.imshow('Image', bboxes_img)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

Below is the final output

[image]

Is there any way to segment the sentence perfectly to get all letters?

Any help or suggestion would be very helpful

Comment: Is this for character recognition (OCR) or a different application? If OCR have you considered using [PyTesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/)?

Comment: @DrBwts, Thank you for your time. it is for different application

Comment: @Nikhil Using a kernel of size (1,1) is not going to have any effect at all. Have you tried varying the kernel size?

Comment: @JeruLuke, Yes I tried to vary it by (2,2) if I set it to (2,2). then it is missing more letters. Size is unable to take the float values

Comment: this text is hard to split trivially. pick a different threshold and hope that you don't catch the light gray pixels where those letters touch. -- or throw AI at the problem. AI is good at this. it can learn what letters look like (OCR). but it's also effort to train and to implement.

Comment: Letters W and N are actually joined in the word brown. It's difficult to separate them

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thank you for your time and advice I will try to implement

Comment: @JeruLuke thank you for your time. yes it's hard to separate the letters I am trying in the another approcah